# BULK INSERT 4866 and 7301

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

Trying to BULK import data in SQL server with below lines but getting error:

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 8, Line 3
>   The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 96. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>
> Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>   Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Is there anything wrong with my statements? As when I use import wizard it works fine.

```
BULK INSERT BICX.dbo.raw
FROM 'D:\NEW_CDR\NEW.txt'
WITH
(
   FIRSTROW = 5,
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample of `NEW.txt`?  I have a hunch that something obvious will be in your input data.

Comment: Please add the `BICX.dbo.raw` table details as well

Comment: raw table contains a total of 95 columns. All with data type varchar(50). While i do the auto import wizard i set the row delimiter as 'LF' and header column delimiter as ',' and rows to skip '5'. I do not face any issue there.

Answer (score 1):

As you say the table contains 95 columns, and the error says column 96 is too long you have a problem with your row delimiter.

If your file came from a windows system it most likely is `\r\n` or you could try `0x0a` if that doesn't work

```
BULK INSERT BICX.dbo.raw
FROM 'D:\NEW_CDR\NEW.txt'
WITH
(
   FIRSTROW = 5,
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
);
```

or

```
BULK INSERT BICX.dbo.raw
FROM 'D:\NEW_CDR\NEW.txt'
WITH
(
   FIRSTROW = 5,
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
);
```

Comment: Nope still did not work. But getting a different error message this time. Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: True that the previous error was showing 96 column, though I have 95 columns to fetch. Somehow may be it is calculating an extra column in the beginning. Any was to delete the first column?

Comment: Problem is solved. The source file had some garbage value on column 1 for which it did not insert that. After deleting it manually the BULK loading was successful. Please let me know how can i delete those garbage value on the last 4 rows of column 1 in SQL statement?